# Hadoop 3.1.1 showing only one live datanode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, firewall, hadoop3, datanode

I installed hadoop 3.1.1 on **3 virtual machines** with VMware on Ubuntu. When I run *hdfs namenode -format* and start-all.sh then ***jps* works correctly** on my master and two slaves nodes.

However, with the command *hdfs dfsadmin -report*, I can see **only one live data node** (I get the same result when I check on master:50070 or 8088).

I tried to disable firewall as follows: *ufw disable* but it didn't solve the problem. The 3 machines can connect with each other (without passwd) with *ping* and *ssh*. I also deleted the hadoop tmp folder with datanode and namenode folders but it didn't work as well. There are also **no issues shown in the log files**.

Do you have any solutions to get **three live datanode instead of one**? Thanks.

---

These are my configurations files:

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
  <value>master</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>master:8025</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>master:8035</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>master:8050</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/namenode</value>
    <final>true</final>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.http-address</name>
    <value>master:50070</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value> 
</property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000/</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.FS</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:9000/</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

workers

```
   master
   slave1
   slave2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem was the firewall. But "ufw" doesn't help. I needed to do those commands:

```
sudo iptables -L -v
sudo iptables -F
sudo iptables -X
sudo iptables -t nat -F
sudo iptables -t nat -X
sudo iptables -t mangle -F
sudo iptables -t mangle -X
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```